# The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "Security.context"

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-3.3

Im following this  [tutorial](http://www.webaki.com/blog/redirection-apres-login-logout-92.html) to redirect user after login, but I got this error while defining the service:

> The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "Security.context".

Im using Symfony3 ,FOSUSERBundle 2.0@dev.

here is my service :

```
    redirect.after.logout:
    class: AppBundle\Redirection\AfterLogoutRedirection
    arguments: ["@router","@Security.context"]
```

after some researches, I found that *Security.context* was removed. I wonder if I can replace it by an other service or how can I fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change your `Security.context` for the `security.authorization_checker`

```
redirect.after.logout:
    class: AppBundle\Redirection\AfterLogoutRedirection
    arguments: ["@router","@security.authorization_checker"]
```

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements